# Transaction between database and a memory task ?

Tags: c#, .net, transactions

I want to make some job in database then some task on memory(like change some values of objects) and i want to combine both task in same transaction.

I am using EF 4.1 and it just provide me SaveChanges method which makes transaction by itself.  Simply if SaveChanges does not throw exception so i can do some task on memory. This is a solution. But it break architecture of application. Because SaveChanges does not called before that task. Task can not know that SaveChanges will be success or fail in future when it is called.

Is it possible to make any transaction between database and memory tasks ?

If it is so how we can do that ?

Answer (score 3):

Juval Lowy has an excellent article in MSDN titled "[Volatile Resource Managers in .NET Bring Transactions to the Common Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163688.aspx)" explaining how to create transactional wrappers around in-memory types.

At its core, you want to implement the [`ISinglePhaseNotification` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.isinglephasenotification.aspx).  Once you have this implemented for the in-memory type you want to be part of the transaction, you have to register it by calling the [`EnlistVolatile` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149780.aspx) on the [`Transaction` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.aspx) to register the instance for notification on the transaction.

Typically, you would make the call to `EnlistVolatile` by looking to see if the static [`Transaction.Current` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.current.aspx) is not null, and if it isn't, registering with that (e.g. this is what classes in the [`System.Data.SqlClient` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t72t3k4.aspx) do to in order to self-register).

However, you can enlist your instance(s) anywhere you wish once you know the `Transaction` is in place (after your [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) is created, for example).

If you don't want to go through the above, you can also subscribe to the [`TransactionCompleted` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.transactioncompleted.aspx) and change the state of your memory variables depending on the state of the `Transaction` returned through the [`Transaction` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactioneventargs.transaction.aspx) on the [`TransactionEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactioneventargs.aspx) passed to the event handler.

You can get the a [`TransactionInformation` instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactioninformation.aspx) through the [`TransactionInformation` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.transactioninformation.aspx) on the `Transaction`.  The `TransactionInformation` class has a [`Status` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactioninformation.status.aspx) which returns a value from the [`TransactionStatus` enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionstatus.aspx) indicating what the status of the transaction is (committed, aborted, etc.).